# Buffer corruption with correctly managed heap

Tags: c, memory-management, heap-memory

I have a heisenbug that occurs so infrequently that it's not replicatable on any environment, it fails spectacularly and I have no idea how to diagnose it.

The bug is related to memory usage.
The corruption doesn't fit into the defined [four categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption) of corruption.

Tooling shows that it is not:

1. Uninitialized memory  (it was previously allocated)
2. Using non-owned memory (it was allocated by the thread and owned by thread)
3. Buffer Overflow   (Boundary checks pass)
4. Faulty heap memory management (this isn't a leak, all memory is freed, and set null defensively)

I say this with some confidence because while I cannot replicate it, logging and tooling in the higher transaction environments indicate the above do not happen.

I'm compiling gcc c11 no optimization, Wall, other minimal flags.

ASAN, electric fence, hellgrind, memcheck, cppcheck find no problems.

Heap management appears to work well with a pool allocator, boundary checks, corruption sentinel.

Absolutely no unit tests

The issue is primarily seen when very very rarely an array is corrupted, invalid boundaries are set there are only 50 items but the count of items gets corrupted and we end up with < 0 or > 50. Core dumps show this. By determining where this array bound comes from and verifying the correct value we can prevent this issue, but then the problem migrates to another location. Since this only affects a single customer and single transaction type that indicates to me something related to this customer or transaction. But that tree has borne no fruit.

Due to how infrequent this occurs I cannot rule out:

1. Another thread corruption
2. Some data race condition
3. Thread race condition
4. Programming error writing to place it shouldn't.

I am unable to run any of the above tooling (ASAN, electric fence, ...) in an environment that simulates the conditions that cause this. But I cannot replicate it any any environment that I can run these toolings.

My only thoughts would be to:

1. Create deep copies or serialize these objects and splice checks throughout the code base. (messy, might be impossible due to memory constraints)
2. Ignore the problem (unevenly effecting a single customer means I cannot do this)
3. Keep playing ping pong and make the codebase even more ugly with all these error checks looking for corruption.
4. Rewrite it all in $Language (not really an option)
5. Try a new pool allocator or arena allocator to see if there's an uknown bug in our custom one.

I'm looking for novel approaches to this that I haven't considered. Ways to automate this, better tooling for these type of problems. How do you validate that an object hasn't changed behind your back?

Comment: This question has little to none value (for this site at least) without the actual code and will get closed as off-topic.

Comment: _Wall_ is not enough, _Wextra_ is better. `ASAN, electric fence, hellgrind, memcheck, cppcheck find no problems` what about _valgrind_ if you can run under it ?

Comment: I'm looking for strategies on how to deal with a specific type of memory corruption. Not really sure how you would like me to show code that indicates that.

Comment: valgrind doesn't find issues here. Other than Wall and Wextra are there any other good [flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html) you'd recommend?

Comment: @will.mont ok, sad, just a remark : in case you go outside a local array or equivalent _valgring_ will see nothing because it doesn't know the size, when I have a doubt I replace them by array in the heap temporarily to have them check. Are you sure the error is not hardware ? that happens ;-)

Comment: Do you write the memory pool allocator in-house? Is so, perhaps you should test that exhaustively in a separate controlled environment. If not, ditto anyway. It's not unknown for proprietory software to have bugs (but try proving it to the supplier!)

Comment: @WeatherVane It was written years ago. I'd like to add tests to it for validation and that's on my list.

Comment: @bruno Also investigating an alternate to the vector implementation that would allow storage of each item in separate pages to work better with electric fence. Intresting there's a new experimental SGcheck for valgrind that has this functionality that memcheck doesn't.

Comment: @will.mont Supposing you compile/run in 64b can you try in 32b (-m32) to change the memory consumption/usage ? or of course from 32 to 64, all of that supposing you are compatible with any architecture of course

Comment: @will.mont I don't know sorry, of course I never have bug in my memory management so I don't need ... ok ok easy joke ^^

Comment: Are threads involved?

Comment: Where in the world is this customer located? Could it be related to the use of 8-bit `char` values that happen to be negative by defaut on your target system. You might want to add `-funsigned-char` to your CFLAGS to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is likely to be closed as off-topic, a general purpose tool that you can use to help track down the root cause in the future is to implement an in-memory ring buffer to record critical events. It is different from regular logs because the log is only to memory, and thus has very low latency. If you have enough memory dedicated to this log, you should be able to inspect it on the next crash for the customer, and get a better idea of the events that led up to the corruption.

A very basic implementation would be:

```
static_assert(0 == (LR_TAPE_SIZE & (LR_TAPE_SIZE-1)),
        "LR_TAPE_SIZE must be a power of 2");
static_assert(LR_TAPE_SIZE > (LR_LOG_MAX + 1),
        "LR_TAPE_SIZE must be larger than LR_LOG_MAX");

struct lr_tape {
    uint32_t wrap :  1;
    uint32_t head : 31;
    char tape[LR_TAPE_SIZE];
};

int
lr_write(struct lr_tape *lr, const void *buf, uint32_t sz)
{
    uint32_t pos = lr->head % LR_TAPE_SIZE;
    uint32_t cnt = LR_TAPE_SIZE - pos;
    memcpy(&lr->tape[pos], buf, (cnt < sz) ? cnt : sz);
    if (cnt < sz) memcpy(&lr->tape[0], buf + cnt, sz - cnt);
    lr->head += sz;
    lr->wrap = lr->wrap || (lr->head >= LR_TAPE_SIZE);
    return sz;
}
```

You can then implement a simple `printf`-like wrapper for it.

```
int
lr_log(struct lr_tape *lr, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    char buf[LR_LOG_MAX + 1];
    va_list ap;
    int r, p;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    r = vsnprintf(buf, LR_LOG_MAX, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    if (r <= 0) return r;
    if (r >= LR_LOG_MAX) {
        r = LR_LOG_MAX;
        buf[r-3] = buf[r-2] = buf[r-1] = '.';
    }
    if (buf[r-1] != '\n') buf[r++] = '\n';
    return lr_write(lr, buf, r);
}
```

And a way to emit it:

```
void
lr_output(struct lr_tape *lr, FILE *out)
{
    uint32_t pos = lr->head % LR_TAPE_SIZE;
    uint32_t cnt = LR_TAPE_SIZE - pos;
    if (lr->head == 0) return;
    if (lr->wrap) {
        fwrite("...", 3, 1, out);
        fwrite(&lr->tape[pos], cnt, 1, out);
    }
    fwrite(lr->tape, pos, 1, out);
}
```

Comment: Indeed.  The best way to figure out what your code is doing?  **Have it tell you.**  Including file/line number/function/function args.